# CSS is there a way to apply border-radius only on background

Tags: html, css

My goal: to place a png image within round colored circle (and create an avatar with margin).

[image]

I can create two different classes one for the background (the pink circle) and another for the image (the cat) like so:

```
.avatar-bg{
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 50%; //make round
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.avatar {
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
}
```

and html will look like this

```
<div class="avatar-bg"><img class="avatar" src="myImg.png"/></div>
```

**Is there a way to consolidate them into one class?**

Comment: Do you mean one class or one element?

Comment: Does the image really need to use the `<img>` element?

Comment: radial-gradient will allow you to draw a round color background. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient()

Comment: @AHaworth one CSS class

Comment: @SalmanA no, but it does need to have the separation of background and image centered in it

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what you mean by 'separation of background and image'> Is there, say, a white part around the avatar before the color circle? An image of what you are aiming for might help us get a proper solution.

Comment: @AHaworth edited the question with an example

Comment: Thanks, that makes it much clearer, I have altered my answer as originally I had understood the format required incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `background` properties and a pseudo element.

```css
.avatar-bg{
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.avatar-bg::after {
  content: '';
  background: url("https://i.pravatar.cc/300") ;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar-bg"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the code, its not exactly what I'm looking for. your code takes the image from https://i.pravatar.cc/300 and makes it a circle, I'm looking to place it on a different color circle - creating a  background & margin for the image

Comment: @KukulaMula I've updated the code with a pseudo element

Answer (score 0):

You can consolidate things into both one class and one element.

(NOTE: the original version of this answer had the formatting the other way round - the whole thing being a circle - this snippet follows the image now shown in the question).

You can put the avatar and a radial gradient as combined background images on just one div. The radial gradient comes first in the list which means it covers part of the avatar so the avatar looks circular.

Obviously you can change the verious %s to get the amount of avatar you want to show within the circle.

```css
.avatar-bg {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: purple;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 0 45%, pink 45% 50%, purple 50% 100%), url(https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200);
  background-size: 100% 100%, 80% 80%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar-bg"></div>
```

Comment: my img source looks as follows `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA...SuQmCC` it's not valid url. is there a different way to set it to `background-image`

Comment: Instead of `background-image: url('https://image/100')`, use `background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA...SuQmCC')`

Comment: I'm assigning `background-color` and `background-image` a variable in javascript like `avatar.setAttribute('style', 'background-image: url(' +  validUuser['avatar'] +')' ); 
 avatar.setAttribute('style', `background-color: ${validUuser['bgcolor']}`); ` and the result is the colored circle without the image

Comment: If you look at the background-image in the code you'll see that it has two parts - but they   need to be set all as one string. The first part is a radial-gradient then after a comma there is the URL. And there is no point in setting an attribite to one thing and then setting it to another. The style needs to be set all as one string otherwise the second string will overwrite the first. Why not use avatar.style.backgroundColor and avatar.style.backgroundImage instead - but remember the image string must include both the radial gradient and the URL.